# Converting number to a number in the specified offset

Tags: math

I need an algorithm that will convert my X to its corresponding slot.
In the image X are the red numbers and the GUI slots are the white numbers.
X is always between 0 and 19.
[image: gui with slots]

So far I've tried `(x % 6) + 12` but it only worked for the first row.
I'm sorry for not explaining it with text only but I simply can't find the right words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `x % 5` gives the 0-based column offset.
- `x / 5` gives the 0-based row offset, where `a / b` stands for C-style integer division with truncation, same as `floor(a / b)` or `(a - (a % b)) / b`.

Putting the two together: `n = 12 + (x % 5) + 9 * (x / 5)`.